# Android not triggering android:parentActivityName

Tags: android

Activity A is the main launcher Activity for my app
A starts Activity B upon some condition
Activity C is the Settings Activity

Android Manifest- C is the parent of B, as shown below:

```
<activity
            android:name=".view.ActivityB"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favorite"
            android:parentActivityName=".view.ActivityC">
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".view.ActivityC" />
        </activity>
```

Flow:

1. I start the app, Activity A is called
2. A starts B
3. When I click on
       back button in the Status Bar, I am routed to A not C. Any clue why
       is this is happening

Comment: Can you share your ActivityB class code please? Are you also setting HopeAsUp?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem understanding how activities are started and finished. Having your example, if activity A starts the activity B it doesn't mean that the system is creating the activity C (simply because is the parent of B) to insert it between A and B, and this is why when back is pressed the activity A is resumed. To add an activity C between A and B without explicitly creating it read [this post](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) about creating a proper back navigation. If you have any problems reply with a comment.

Comment: Actually, the poster has it right. He is not hitting the back button, he's hitting the action back Home button which should go back to the parent activity as specified in the manifest. At least based on my understanding of the android docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the confusion:

The android `Back Button` is calling (popping) the top of Back Stack so if not manually manipulated, it contains the last called activity. In your case `Activity A` is called just before `Activity B` so the top of the Back Stack is `Activity A`

But there is another soft back button in the android as displayed in the following image:

[image]

it is usually displayed in the top left corner of the screen. The behavior of this button is what is described in your `Manifest`. So if you are in `Activity B` and you press this button you will go to `Activity C` instead of `Activity A`

You can manually change the behavior of the `Back Button` with [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html)

Comment: And it doesn't work. I have the same issue. It seems that parentActivityName needs to be set but is ignored and always goes back to the launcher activity. Which in this case, is just the same result as hitting the Back button.